# Unable to connect to cassandra 4.1.3 version from springoot 3.1.1 version

Tags: java, spring, cassandra

```
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'cassandraSessionFactory' defined in class path resource [com/test/config/CassandraConfig.class]: Unsatisfied dependency expressed through method 'cassandraSessionFactory' parameter 0: Error creating bean with name 'cassandraSession' defined in class path resource [com/test/config/CassandraConfig.class]: Could not reach any contact point, make sure you've provided valid addresses (showing first 1 nodes, use getAllErrors() for more): Node(endPoint=cassandra/<unresolved>:9042, hostId=null, hashCode=65654666): [com.datastax.oss.driver.api.core.connection.ConnectionInitException: [s0|control|connecting...] Protocol initialization request, step 1 (OPTIONS): failed to send request (io.netty.channel.StacklessClosedChannelException)]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.createArgumentArray(ConstructorResolver.java:800) ~[spring-beans-6.0.10.jar!/:6.0.10]
        at
```

```java
@Bean
public CqlSessionFactoryBean cassandraSession() {
    CqlSessionFactoryBean session = new CqlSessionFactoryBean();
    session.setContactPoints("cassandra");
    session.setKeyspaceCreations(getKeyspaceCreations());
    session.setKeyspaceName(keySpace);
    session.setPort(port);
    session.setUsername(userName);
    session.setPassword(password);
    session.setLocalDatacenter(datacenter);
    session.setSessionBuilderConfigurer(sessionBuilder -> sessionBuilder
            .withConfigLoader(DriverConfigLoader
                    .programmaticBuilder()
                    .withString(DefaultDriverOption.REQUEST_TIMEOUT, "10 seconds")
                    .build()));
    return session;
}
```

```xml
<parent>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
    <version>3.1.1</version>
    <relativePath /> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
</parent>
```

```xml
<dependency>
<groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
<artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-cassandra</artifactId>
<version>4.1.3</version>
</dependency>
```

Comment: _"Could not reach any contact point, make sure you've provided valid addresses (showing first 1 nodes, use getAllErrors() for more): Node(endPoint=cassandra/:9042, hostId=null, hashCode=65654666)"_

Comment: There is no `spring-boot-starter-data-cassandra` 4.1.3, even if it would you shouldn't include versions for Spring Boot managed starters.

Comment: Connected to cassandra at 127.0.0.1:9042
[cqlsh 6.1.0 | Cassandra 4.1.3 | CQL spec 3.4.6 | Native protocol v5]
Use HELP for help.
cassandra@cqlsh>
cassandra@cqlsh> desc keyspaces;

cassandra is running fine

Comment: Its a typo spring-boot-data-cassandra is 3.1.1 and spring-data-cassandra-parent is 4.1.3

Comment: Don't mess around with versions, the version for `spring-boot-starter-data-cassandra` should be managed by your `spring-boot-starter-parent` and don't mix versions from different spring boot versions as that is trouble waiting to happen. ALso don't just change a parent version or dependency version as that will cascade into all sorts of issues.

Answer (score 0):

I see no *blocking* error with the code you provided. But as mentionned above this is the only thing you need in your POM.

```xml
<dependency>
 <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
 <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-cassandra</artifactId>
 <version>3.1.3</version>
</dependency>
```

The error message tells us the host `cassandra` is not resolved by your java
code.

```
Could not reach any contact point, make sure 
you've provided valid addresses (showing first 1 nodes, use getAllErrors() for more)
```

In a comment, you provided an output from `cqlsh` telling us the DB is started and working but the message give you the **name of your cluster, and not the host of the cassandra node.**. Check what the cqlsh output look likes with a docker image..obviously  `Test Cluster` is not the host.

```
Connected to Test Cluster at 127.0.0.1:9042
[cqlsh 6.0.0 | Cassandra 4.0.7-9cb79586cc78 | CQL spec 3.4.5 | Native protocol v5]
Use HELP for help.
cqlsh>
```

**Couple of ideas:**

- Connect ssh to the cassandra node and show the IP with `ifconfig`
- Change "cassandra" by correct IP of add an entry to `/etc/config`

Comment: He is using Spring boot 3.1.1, when using starters don't mix modules from different spring boot versions as that will lead to all sorts of vague issues.

Comment: ssh cassandra@10.42.xxx.xxx
ssh: connect to host 10.42.xxx.xxx port 22: Connection refused     and host is not Test Cluster in my above comment in question its cassandra only

Comment: And version 4.1.3 is getting write timedout for 3-4 consecutive writes